# Show message in Alert Dialog

Tags: android, dialog, message

Trying to dynamically change the message of an AlertDialog. For some reason I get a blank dialog box with no message.

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int dialogId, Bundle args) {
switch (dialogId) {
case ABOUT_DIALOG:
    AlertDialog.Builder aboutDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    return aboutDialog.create();
}
}
@Override
protected void onPrepareDialog(int dialogId, Dialog dialog, Bundle args){
super.onPrepareDialog(dialogId, dialog, args);
switch(dialogId){
case ABOUT_DIALOG:
    AlertDialog aboutDialog = (AlertDialog) dialog;
    aboutDialog.setMessage("hello world");
}
}
```

How can I dynamically change the content of an Alert Dialog?

Comment: explain what you exactly want...?

Comment: @siten I'd like to change the text of the Alert Dialog each time it is opened. Sometimes it should be "hello world", sometimes "goodbye world". I set the message onPrepareDialog, but I get a blank dialog box..

Comment: ok same thing i apply in my app but i take septate dialog method.. n where hello word is use call that method as vice versa...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In onCreateDialog() do aboutDialog.setMessage(""); (or just any other dummy message).
If the dialog is missing a message when created, you cannot set it later.

Answer (score 0):

In my own implementation of `onPrepareDialog()` I'm not calling `super.onPrepareDialog`.  Try removing that line and check the behaviour.